# keypress event doesn't log input value first time event is fired

Tags: javascript, settimeout, onkeypress

The first time a `keypress` event fires, it logs an empty input value even though the input has a value. The second time it logs the value but is one keystroke behind in comparison with the input's value. You can check this behavior on the next example:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
{
    const input = document.querySelector('input');

    input.addEventListener('keypress', e =>
    {
        console.log(e.target.value);
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
```

However, the next workaround makes it work, even though I pass in `0ms`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
{
    const input = document.querySelector('input');

    input.addEventListener('keypress', e =>
    {
        setTimeout(() => console.log(e.target.value), 0);
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
```

Why is this hapenning?

Comment: For future reference, the [`keypress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) event is deprecated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you press a `key` for the first time, the value assigned to the **input** is `empty` at the time the `keypress` event takes place, then the character is added to the input, but a moment later. This same is valid for future `keypress` events, the value of the `input` you read is the previous before the `input changes`. Also, if you read on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) there is a warning about keypress being dropped. Hence, and instead, you may want to listen on `keyup` event as shown on the next example:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('keyup', e =>
{
    console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that if what you care about is the fact that the `input` value changed and not specifically that keys were pressed, there is also an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event for that exact purpose.

Answer (score 2):

`keypress` event dont change input `value` - you read 'old' value - current key is in `e.key`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const input = document.querySelector('input');
  input.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    console.log('value',e.target.value);
    console.log('key',e.key);
  });
});
```

```html
<input>
```

you can use `onkeyup` event to have current value in `event.target.value`

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const input = document.querySelector('input');
  input.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    console.log('value', e.target.value);
    console.log('key', e.key);
  });
});
```

```html
<input>
```

The input value will be update before `setTimeout` function will be executed (even for 0 ms) - keyword: js [event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Answer (score 2):

According to [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

> The keypress event is sent to an element when the browser registers
>   keyboard input. This is similar to the keydown event, except that
>   modifier and non-printing keys such as Shift, Esc, and delete trigger
>   keydown events but not keypress events. Other differences between the
>   two events may arise depending on platform and browser.
>
> The keyup event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on
>   the keyboard.
>
> The oninput event it's an event that triggers whenever the input
>   changes.

So the `keypress` will be fired before the value change, use `keyup` instead

About the `setTimeout`, when you put the codes in that place, it will be Asynchronous function (even for 0 ms). In javascript, the Asynchronous function will be executed after all Synchronous commands are finished

Comment: Even though your answer is correct, you probably shouldn't quote from the jQuery documentation here, as jQuery has its own event system, and the question doesn't involve jQuery at all. Better to refer to MDN for example.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's being fired before the input value is updating.  You can try using `keyUp` instead of `keyPress`.

Answer (score 0):

The `keyup` event fires when the key is released which generates the feeling of a little delay. I'd rather prefer to use the `keydown` event which have the same behavior as the OP is exposing. *(Note that the `keypress` event is now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event))*.

Instead of waiting for the next tick (by using `setTimeout`) you can concatenate the current value with the pressed key:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const input = document.getElementById('input');

  input.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    console.log(event.target.value + event.key);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

**EDIT:** After trying this solution a little more, it fails to work as expected when moving the cursor between the input text or when reaching a `maxlength`, so after all I ended up using the workaround proposed by the OP with `setTimeout` and a timeout of 0