# convert JQuery into addEventListener for keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I needed to craete an input which only accepts number. For that, I have created an input with type text and only accepts 5 digits of length.

```
<input id="inputNumber" type="text" maxlength="5">
```

For accepting only number, I created jquery code like the following.

```
$("#inputNumber").keypress(function (value) {
// If the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
if (value.which != 8 && value.which != 0 && (value.which < 48 || value.which > 57)) {
return false;
}
else {
return true;
}
});
```

I tried to convert it into AddEventListner for my Type script file but failed. I even tried below method but failed again. How can I resolve this.

Referece: [keypress event doesn't log input value first time event is fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56248925/keypress-event-doesnt-log-input-value-first-time-event-is-fired)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for js equivalent code that might look like:

```js
const inputNumber = document.querySelector("#inputNumber");

inputNumber.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {

  if (isNaN(event.key)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="inputNumber" type="text" maxlength="5">
```

> I needed to craete an input which only accepts number.

You can use `input type="number"` instead or simplify validation to `!isNaN(event.key)`

```js
const inputNumber = document.querySelector("#inputNumber") as HTMLInputElement;

inputNumber.addEventListener("keydown", (event: KeyboardEvent) => {

  if (isNaN(Number(event.key))) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: But it is still accepting text....I need only numbers to be accepted

Comment: Updated answer. Now it should be okay.

Comment: I am getting error when I used your code in TypeScript specially in isNaN(event.key) line. It is showing  **Property key does not exist on type event**. How to resolve this?

Comment: change `(event)`  to `(event: KeyboardEvent)`

Comment: Changed to (event: KeyboardEvent) but getting Error 

**Error** TS2769 (TS) No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "fullscreenchange" | "fullscreenerror", listener: (this: Element, ev: Event) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.

Comment: and this error too: **Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'**

Comment: For that one change `isNaN(event.key)` to `isNaN(Number(event.key))`. As for previous error I see [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) event is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882144/replacement-for-deprecated-keypress-dom-event) so you can change it to [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event)

Comment: Did this **addEventListener("keydown", (event)** and **(isNaN(Number(event.key)))** and showing same error. Property key does not exist on type event

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: thank you it is working perfectly but I have only one issue I am not able to use backspace button to remove unwanted number.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below **keydown** event and prevent the characters based on the **keycode**?

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
     var inputNumber = document.getElementById('inputNumber');
  inputNumber.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
                        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode ==  13 || event.keyCode == 190 || event.keyCode == 110 || (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39) || event.keyCode == 189) {
                            return
                        } else {
                            if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                                event.preventDefault()
                            }
                        }
    })
});
```

```html
<input id="inputNumber" type="text" maxlength="5"/>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I need addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', .........) for above functionality

Comment: @AbhiSingh Please check updated code which uses addEventlister